# First Steps into Scala

Tags: scala

I m trying to learn scala these days.

I get confused with `_` operator.
How can I use it in the following program ?

Also how this program can be made more concise ?

I have learnt that scala promotes the use of `val` over `var`, in this case how can we use `val` for `balance` ?

```
private object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val acc1 = new PiggyBank(5)
    acc1.printBalance
    acc1 deposit 5
    acc1.printBalance
    acc1 withdraw 5
    acc1.printBalance
  }
}

private class PiggyBank(open_Bal: Int) {
  var balance = open_Bal
  def deposit(value: Int) = balance = balance + value
  def printBalance = println(balance)
  def iswithdrawable(value: Int) =  balance >= value
  def withdraw(value: Int) = {
    if (iswithdrawable(value)) {
      balance = balance - value
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I am scala n00b, but I guess, balance got to be `var`. And `var` is purposefully made for this tasks so that you can mutate it over.

Comment: any idea about '_'.. how can I use it here ?

Comment: I, with my limited ability in Scala, could not find out a place where you'd use `_` unless you force it.

Comment: @Shrey BTW, it is better to split questions and ask them one per post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably going to get a million answers here :)  But, based on the content of your question, you need to read a book.  I'd recommend [Programming in Scala 2nd Edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed).  I've read it twice and it's gotten dog-eared and coffee stained in the process.

The reason I say this is because Scala presents you with a new paradigm, and you're writing Java code in Scala.  This is perfectly fine for starters but you're not going to learn what you want to learn that way.  The book is a great start that will give you the foundation to learn more.

For example, here's what I'd change in your code:

```
case class PiggyBank(balance: Double) {
  def deposit(amount: Double) = PiggyBank(balance + amount)
  def withdraw(amount: Double): Option[PiggyBank] = {
    if (balance >= amount) Some(PiggyBank(balance - amount))
    else None
  }
  override def toString() = balance.toString
}
```

But "why" I would want to do it that way is the real question, and it's that question that you really need to have answered, I argue.  In a nutshell, it's immutable and a bit more functional (although, this is a toy example and there's tons of room for improvement here), but why is it and why do we care?  Books answer this stuff.

Given that, you can start to use the `_` a bit if you want.  For example:

```
val result = PiggyBank(500) withdraw 200 flatMap { _.withdraw(200) } 
println(result.getOrElse(0))
```

But if you're like most noobs (like me a long while ago), you're going to ask "Why on earth is that better??".  That's not an answer you're going to find in a quick SO post.  I could go on and on and on and on but the bottom line is that there are books out there that have already done that, and have done that better than I can.

Comment: Thnk you so much.. m reading Programming in Scala.. but was confused with applying the knowledge..

Comment: Awesome!  Good stuff.  Then all I can say is, just give it time. :)  You're clearly in the early stages of the book; more will become clear as you continue.

Comment: this code works fine.. but it creates a new problem now..  here even both piggybanks have same balance but `if` evalutes to be `false` why so? how to get arround these ? `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val acc1 = PiggyBank(5) deposit 5 withdraw 3
    println(acc1)
    val acc2 = PiggyBank(7)
    println(acc2)
    if (acc1 == acc2) {
      println("equal balance : " + acc1);
    }
  }`

Comment: They're not the same type.  `withdraw` returns an `Option`.  If you ever are concerned about this stuff, specify the type you expect in the `val` - i.e. `val acc1: PiggyBank = ...` <- that will fail to compile.

Comment: yeah.. that I understood.. but how shud I get around this ? (sorry.. newbie.. )

Comment: `if (acc1 map { _ == acc2 } getOrElse(false)) println("equal balance : " + acc2)`

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for _ here. _ is not an operator, but a placeholder for parameters in closures. E.g. when you call a foldLeft an a collection of integers to you sum them up you could write `List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)` instead of `List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(0)((x,y) => x + y)`. The first _ will be the x in the second example and the second _ the y.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `val` with immutable objects. Since your PiggyBank is mutable, you need `var` for the mutable internal state.

You could turn your PiggyBank in immutable this way (basically creating a new immutable object each operation that would change the state of the object):

```
class PiggyBank(val balance : Int) {
  def deposit(value: Int) = new PiggyBank(balance + value)

  def printBalance = println(balance)
  def iswithdrawable(value: Int) =  balance >= value

  def withdraw(value: Int) = if (iswithdrawable(value)) new PiggyBank(balance - value) else this;
  }
```

So you could write  this:

```
object Main {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       val acc1 = new PiggyBank(5) deposit 5 withdraw 5
       acc1.printBalance
  }
```

Comment: basically create a new object instead of mutating the internal state ?

Comment: @Shrey yes. Turn each operation changing the internal state into a function return a new object with the new internal state

Comment: And try to avoid side effects.  For example, `printBalance` is really kind of a bad idea since it's a side effect - it's better to just override `toString` and leave output to something else.  As well, `withdraw` has an error associated with it and when that happens, it's best to use the error-context you get with `Option`.

Comment: @DerekWyatt i agree, I just turned it into immutable since the OP asked about var and val

Comment: @DerekWyatt  I m really sorry.. but wads wrong with withdraw ? I know not the use of `Option` :(

Comment: You'll get there. For now, put simply, `Option` adds an error context to an expression.  You know that `withdraw` may not work, and returning `Option` expresses that idea.  The power comes from the higher order functions on `Option`. Play with it. Try a couple dozen more withdraw operations with `flatMap`.  i.e. `withdraw 200 flatMap { _.withdraw(200) } flatMap { _.withdraw(200) } flatMap { _.withdraw(200) }`.  It'll be unfamiliar for a while - you're learning a new paradigm, not just a new syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding underscore/wildcards, these are helpful reads, "_" is frequently encountered in idiomatic code:

http://www.slideshare.net/normation/scala-dreaded

http://agileskills2.org/blog/2011/05/01/revealing-the-scala-magicians-code-expression/

---

Book index for Staircase vers. 2 has 7 entries for "_":

"curried functions", "existential types", "function literals",

"in identifiers" "import statements" "match expressions" and "initialize field to default value"

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/book-index.html#indexanchor

---

very telling comment: *underscore as a wildcard at both the term and type level plus as a way to coerce a method into a first class function.*

http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2808#comment-41717