# what does it mean assign "_" to a field in scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

I saw some scala code that assign "_" to a field of class, what does it mean ? Thanks

```
private var tk: TaggedKey = _
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581444/first-steps-into-scala/9612735#9612735   (I tried overview of ~ 10 usages of "_" in the language:

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means: *assign default value*. Default value is defined as `null`, `0` or `false` depending on the target type.

It is described in *4.2 Variable Declarations and Definitions* of the [*The Scala Language
Specification*](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> A variable definition `var x : T = _` can appear only as a member of a template. It
>   introduces a mutable field with type T and a default initial value. The default value
>   depends on the type T as follows:
>
> `0` - if `T`is Int or one of its subrange types,
>
> `0L` - if `T`is Long,
>
> `0.0f` - if `T`is Float,
>
> `0.0d` - if `T`is Double,
>
> `false` - if `T`is Boolean,
>
> `()` - if `T`is Unit,
>
> `null` - for all other types `T`.