# How to return null from a generic function in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, null

I am writing my own simple `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation, the only method of it I need to work is `getConnection: Connection`, but the interface inherits many other methods (which I don't need) from `javax.sql.CommonDataSource` and `java.sql.Wrapper`. So, I would like to "implement" those unneeded methods a way they wouldn't actually work but would behave an adequate way when called. For example I implement `boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface)` as

```
def isWrapperFor(iface: Class[_]): Boolean = false
```

and I'd like to implement `<T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface)` as

```
def unwrap[T](iface: Class[T]): T = null
```

But the last doesn't work: the compiler reports type mismatch.

Will it be correct to use `null.asInstanceOf[T]` or is there a better way? Of course I consider just throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` instead in this particular case, but IMHO the question can still be interesting.

Answer (score 26):

This is because `T` could be a non-nullable type. It works when you enforce `T` to be a nullable type:

```
def unwrap[T >: Null](iface: Class[T]): T = null

unwrap(classOf[String]) // compiles

unwrap(classOf[Int]) // does not compile, because Int is not nullable
```

Comment: Didn't new that there are non-nullable types in Scala... I thought `Int` is nullable unlike Java primitive `int`...

Comment: Int is of type AnyVal and value types are not nullable.

Comment: as @oxbow_lakes mentions though, throwing is preferable to returning null in most cases

Comment: This helped me out (trying to write a helper that makes it easier to call a Java library). As a side note do you know why you can't you use an upper bound of AnyRef? I thought Null a subtype of all reference classes?

Comment: You can use `AnyRef`, but then you have to cast `null` to `T`. Also I think it's just clearer to say this type has to be nullable instead of saying it has to be a reference type.

Answer (score 6):

The "correct" solution is to do something which will *immediately* fail. Like so:

```
def unwrap[T](iface: Class[T]): T = sys.error("unimplemented")
```

In scala **2.10**, this would have been implemented as:

```
def unwrap[T](iface: Class[T]): T = ???
```

Because there is a new method in `Predef` called `???`. This works because an expression of the form `throw new Exception` has the type `Nothing`, which is a subtype of any type (it is called *bottom* in type-theoretical circles).

The reason that this is *correct* is that it is much better to fail instantly with an error, rather than use a `null` which may fail later and obfuscate the cause.

Comment: I haven't dealt with `isWrapperFor`/`unwrap` in practice but suppose that `unwrap` is to equal null in case `isWrapperFor` equals false and implementing `isWrapperFor` as `= null` seems the most adequate in case the object can never be a wrapper. Am I not right?

Comment: def ??? = throw new UnsupportedOperationException // very easy to add in Scala < 2.10

Answer (score 1):

**As said in comments, this solution doesn't work**

If I understood your problem well, you can also assign default values, as explained in details in [what does it mean assign "_" to a field in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040886/what-does-it-mean-assign-to-a-field-in-scala). You can find more infos in *4.2 Variable Declarations and Definitions* of the [*The Scala Language
Specification*](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)

So you can simply do:

```
def unwrap[T](iface: Class[T]): T = _
```

which will set `unwrap` with `null` without the type mismatch.

Comment: That is true, I didn't know this didn't work with functions, which by the way is sad. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

You can use option:

```html
def nullHandledFunctionCall[T]( obj: Option[T], function: T=>T ) = {
    if(obj == null){
      None
    }else{
      obj.map(function)
    }
  }
```