# How to return null from a function expecting a return type T

Tags: scala, generics

I have a method which deserialise data and returns a type T. But, I need to handle a condition where I need to return null if the data is null. I am getting a compiler when trying to return null.

```
class TransactionDeserializer[T] extends Deserializer[T] {

  override def deserialize(topic: String, data: Array[Byte]): T = {
    if (data == null){
      return null //Getting compilation error here
    } else {
      val objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
      val obj = objIn.readObject().asInstanceOf[T]
      objIn.close
      obj
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `null.asInstanceOf[T]` should make the compiler pass.

Comment: You can do this `TransactionDeserializer[T >: Null]` and it should work. - BTW, as a side note / advice, consider using **Option[T]** for the return type of deserialize instead of **T**, and use `None` for `null`. Also, consider the **typeclass** pattern for this use case.

Comment: Both comments above work. The reason you need to cast or inherit Null because a generic T implies directly inheriting from Any, which could be either an AnyVal or AnyRef. Only AnyRef can be assigned to null, and AnyVal cannot (although you can force cast)

Comment: you should alter TransactionDeserializer[T] as TransactionDeserializer[T >: Null]

Comment: `[T <: AnyRef]` is another option.

Comment: Thanks all, it worked! All of the above explanation makes sense.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066062/2707792) is essentially @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez's comment, so I'd say it's a duplicate.